# It finds a file but it does not "scan" it (Java, Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I am using Eclipse Luna Java EE, and moved a previous project to it. I am trying to read a .txt file. I know that the program "sees" the file, but when it tests the scanner object to check if it "hasNext", the result is always false.

Is there something I'm missing?

```
    package visualLaw;
//package system;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ParseFile {    
    public static void main (String[] args){                


            File plan = new File("plan.txt");
            final ReadFile rf = new ReadFile(plan);
}
} 


    class ReadFile{

    Scanner s =null;
        ReadFile(File file){

        try {
            s = new Scanner (file);

            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("FEIL: argsfilen");
        }
```

In the above code, I get the url displayed correctly, and all.
But when I execute the code below, it does not read a single line, and if I try it without testing, it gives me a nullpoint error.

```
        while(s.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Did I get here?");
            try {
                tag = s.next();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("FEIL: argsfilen");
            }
} 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the encoding type in scanner:

```
s = new Scanner (file, "ISO-8859-1");
```

If that still does not work, it may be because Scanner uses whitespace as default delimiter and your file may be empty or containing only whitespaces. Try this as well:

```
s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)));
```

Let me know how it goes! :)

Comment: thanks a lot. I didn't even try, what I did was to change the enconding of my whole project to UTF-8 - it was US-ASCII. Since I was migrating from a pure Java project to a Dynamic Web Project, it somehow got it as US-ASCII, and thus the file didn't work.

Comment: encoding is a sneaky devil! :) plz accept the answer if it helped. thnx.

Comment: I suggest always using UTF-8 and throw ASCII, ANSI and Windows-1252 out of the window.